# Align 2 classes with the same name horizontally

Tags: html, css, class

Doing the MIMO HTML course and I've come across an issue where i cant get both elements with the `class="column"` attribute to align horizontally with `display: inline-block;`

I've already tried `float:right` and other properties to make them line up but something is stopping this happening

```css
.column {
  min-width: 300px; /*DOES NOT WORK*/
  display: inline-block; /*DOES NOT WORK*/
  vertical-align: top; /*DOES NOT WORK*/
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <!--Footer-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column">
      <h4>My Links
        <!--My Links Header-->
      </h4>
      <p>
        <a href="https://soundcloud.com/discover">Soundcloud <!--Link-->
                </a>
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com">Youtube <!--Link-->
                </a>
      </p </div>
      <div class="column">
        <!--My Story Header-->
        <h4>My Story
        </h4>
        <p>Hey there! I'm aspiring music website creator!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The `display: inline-block;` should put the elements side-by-side according to MIMO but this doesn't happen

Comment: You need to close the `p` tag. Otherwise the next column becomes a nested column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can float it to left.
you also have a wrong closing tag here...
**`</p </div>`**

```css
.column {
  min-width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <!--Footer-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column">
      <h4>My Links
        <!--My Links Header-->
      </h4>
      <p>
        <a href="https://soundcloud.com/discover">Soundcloud <!--Link--></a>
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com">Youtube <!--Link--></a>
      </p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <!--My Story Header-->
        <h4>My Story
        </h4>
        <p>Hey there! I'm aspiring music website creator!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can avoid using float by closing the `<p>` tag in the first column and it'll work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the broken `</p` in your HTML. And add `float: left;` to the `column` class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example:

```css
.column {
  min-width: 300px; /*DOES NOT WORK*/
display: inline-block; /*DOES NOT WORK*/
vertical-align: top; /*DOES NOT WORK*/
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <!--Footer-->
  <div class="container">
  
    <div class="column">
      <h4>My Links
        <!--My Links Header-->
      </h4>
      <p>
        <a href="https://soundcloud.com/discover">Soundcloud <!--Link-->
                </a>
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com">Youtube</a>
      </p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="column">
        <!--My Story Header-->
        <h4>My Story
        </h4>
        <p>Hey there! I'm aspiring music website creator!
        </p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `flex`. In your case, you would need to set the display to `flex` to  to `.container`:

```
.container{
  display: flex;
}
```

If you want both children to have the same width you can simply add `flex: 1` to their CSS properties.

You can check the following snippet.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}

.column{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <!--Footer-->
  <div class="container">
  
    <div class="column">
      <h4>My Links
        <!--My Links Header-->
      </h4>
      <p>
        <a href="https://soundcloud.com/discover">Soundcloud <!--Link-->
                </a>
        <br>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com">Youtube</a>
      </p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="column">
        <!--My Story Header-->
        <h4>My Story
        </h4>
        <p>Hey there! I'm aspiring music website creator!
        </p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```